# Python threading and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

This is my code:

```
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo(x, y):
    x += 5
    y.append(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 0
    y = []

    thread = Thread(target=foo, args=(x, y,))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()

    print 'Value of x is: ' + str(x)
    print 'Value of y is: ' + str(y)
```

When i run this code, the result is:

```
Value of x is: 0
Value of y is: [5]
```

When i change the Thread into Process, the result is:

```
Value of x is: 0
Value of y is: []
```

Why the +5 for x doesn't work while the append for y works?

And, why when i use Process both +5 and append don't work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) before asking basic questions as it will save everyone's time including yours.

In short, when you use `Thread`, the main thread and launched thread share the same memory space but the `x` in function `foo` is another internal `x` but not the same `x` outside. So you just change the internal `x` but not the `x` outside. Further, actually `y` is also an internal `y`, but you are changing what it points to but not itself. You can confirm this by change `y.append(5)` to `y = [0]` to see will the outside `y` change.

And, when you use `Process`, the main thread and launched process hold totally separate memory space.